# Spring security authentification methods

Tags: spring-security

I'm new in spring security. In my actual application no spring, it has some methods of authetification, for example, some systems are authenticated by xml document, other systems are authenticated by url with parameters, other system are authenticated by webservices and other system  are authenticated by json documents . In my new spring security application at the moment only  authetification by login form, but I try  bypass login form, to implement the others authentification, but at the moment i don't  know to do it. Can anybody help me how to implement the others authentifications?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need "Multiple Authentication Provider". Have a look to these documents, it explains how to authenticate using Login Form and Restful:

[Spring security for both web services and users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288467/spring-security-for-both-web-services-and-users/)

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/spring-security-two-security-realms-in-one-application/

[Spring security with multiple authentication providers - UsernameNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349219/spring-security-with-multiple-authentication-providers-usernamenotfoundexcepti)

http://www.networkedassets.com/configuring-spring-security-for-a-restful-web-services/

Answer (score 0):

4th link works for me,  when i set in my navigator http://localhost:8080/rresclick/apiloginuser?username=username&password=password I authenticate well and  not show login form. After authentificate,  it went to controller. 
Now i want to do not show  login form when I recive a xml document with user and password. it has do the same.